# Font-Awesome with Sliding JQuery Code Error

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I was creating a JQuery sliding navigation using Font Awesome (SEE: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Now upon adding CSS since this is a third party web fonts icons I wonder how can I apply it to my own code using the + and - icon.

```
+ -> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> fa-plus

- -> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> fa-minus
```

my jQuery code is.

```
$("#toggle > li > div").click(function(){
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#toggle ul').slideUp();  
        $("span.minus-btn").removeClass('minus-btn');
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});


$("#toggle > li > div").click(function() {

         $("#toggle > li > div").removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass('active');

if($(this).hasClass("active")){
       $("span.plus-btn", this).toggleClass('minus-btn');
         }
});
```

Now I am stock I don't even know how to fix the sizes of icons. Please help.

Here's the JQuery Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/SG7LZ/6/

Any great help + explanation please?

Please show me the solution on JSFiddle so that I can check on the code and results.

A big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found it difficult to get around your code, so I made a new fiddle.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nejo/qE6u9/4/)

To change an icon, you have to get to the `i.fa` element and remove the `.fa-plus` class and add a `.fa-minus` class.

Also, you set the size of the icon by adding one of these classes: `.fa-2x, .fa-3x, .fa-4x, .fa-5x`.